# Past Perfect or Present Perfect in context

Tags: tense

I have a problem of choosing the appropriate tense in this context:

I went shopping with my friend, saw an interesting thing and after we got out of the shop I should say:

A: I haven't seen that [the thing] here before.
B: I hadn't seen that [the thing] here before.

Comment: Hi, J. Doe - have you reviewed what the past perfect and present perfect mean at resources like https://englishlive.ef.com/blog/language-lab/english-grammar-help-present-perfect-and-past-perfect/ ?

Answer (score 1):

If the shopping has just happened in the present you say: "I haven`t seen that here before", you are talking to your friend while you are leaving the shop. Looking to the past from the present.

Your sentence is written in the past tense, so the shopping happened in the past. You are looking further back from that moment, so the past perfect would be appropriate, because you had not seen it before the shopping which happened in the past. Looking to the past from the past.